# Ruby - playing simple wav file

Tags: ruby

I'm working on basic sound notification scripts and I'm using mpg123 and mp3 files because I want a very, very lightweight way to play sound files. I would much prefer to use wav, but mpg123 is extremely small.

**Is there a simple way to play wav files in Ruby?**

Having pitch control etc. would be nice, but right now I just want efficiency as running an external app is pretty clunky.

Thanks!

Comment: "wav" is pointless for describing audio. it's a container format intended for all sorts of different audio codecs, including mp3. saying you want to play a "wav" is like saying you want to eat "food".

Comment: @Marc B This confuses me, but what do you suggest for something that doesn't degrade quickly? I had a 0.6s mp3 file that went POOF on me today. I didn't write to it. It just died. It was about 2 weeks old. I get the impression that mp3 is not meant to be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an external program for playing files. I've used afplay successfully in the past

Comment: Ugh, I really don't. I mean, right now, it's not a big deal. mpg123 is < 1MB. It runs fast. But I want to get down as basic and as fast as possible. I may have to wait until I have the ability to write something in C.